# Specify input field width base on character size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the input field to make sure user can see the total length of the input field.

for example

```
<input size='60' type='text'/>
```

I want the user to see the total 60 characters at once instead of see the total length being truncated to around 50.

I can't specify the input field width because there is not way to know what the width will be (could be short or long and it's dynamic).

http://jsfiddle.net/j2KrZ/4/

Can anyone have an idea of how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: This may show what I think you mean better: http://jsfiddle.net/VBwCD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat clunky approach, which iterates over each `input` element, creates a `div`, copies the CSS of the `input` to that created `div`, applies a `float` (to allow its width to be determined by its contents) and then assigns that width to the `input` (and removes the created-element):

```
$('input[type="text"]').css('width', function (){
    // gets the applied style as it appears once rendered in the page:
    var styles = window.getComputedStyle(this, null),
    // temporary element:
        tmp = document.createElement('div');

    // creates a textNode child for the div, containing the value of the input:
    tmp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.value));

    // sets the style attribute of the div to those styles of the input
    // (note that 'tmp.style = styles['cssText']' did not work, sadly):
    tmp.setAttribute('style', styles['cssText']);

    // floating, so the width is determined by the content, not the parent-width:
    tmp.style.float = 'left';

    // appends the div to the body:
    document.body.appendChild(tmp);

    // gets the rendered width of the div and stores it:
    var w = window.getComputedStyle(tmp, null).width;

    // removes the div, since it's no longer required:
    tmp.parentNode.removeChild(tmp);

    // returns the width, to set the width of the input element:
    return w;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j2KrZ/12/).

Answer (score 3):

If you use a [Monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) (fixed width per character) the input box width should accommodate up to 60 characters exactly.  Tested in IE10, Firefox 22 and Chrome 30.0.1599.69

Example of a monospaced font in use to fix this:

`<input size='60' maxlength='60' style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;" type='text' value='123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'/>`

Comment: I have no idea how older browsers calculate the input width but you should test it yourself as it may be fine.

Comment: This works on old browsers too. The box can be slightly too big at times, but this should be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a dynamic input width you can use an event handler:

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    $(this).width($("input").val().length * w); // w = width of a single char (if monospace), otherwise max char width    
});
```